# articles in "A game in normal form"

Tags: grammar, zero-article, mathematics

I would like to know why there is no article (say "a") in front of the word "normal" in the phrase

*A game in normal form*?

This phrase is standard in game theory.

Comment: It's really just idiomatic preference in this exact context. There's nothing wrong with [...*in **the** normal form*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in+the+normal+form%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), as can be seen from the number of times that occurs in Google Books. Note that if we change the adjective to ***standard*** the article remains optional, but idiomatically we invariably include it with, say, *in the **usual** form*. And we never include it with certain nouns - for example, *...in normal **English***.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that it's strictly incorrect to do so. It's just that it's more idiomatic to say "in normal form".

We don't say

> the game is in the normal form

in game theory for the same reason that we don't say

> the patient is in the surgery

in medicine. The articles are typically elided by native speakers.